# Как правильно - "наебну́лся" или "наёбнулся"?

Tags: ударение, мат, словоупотребление

Как правильно - наебну́лся или наёбнулся?

Comment: ну вы же прекрасно понимаете что это зависит от статистики словоупотребления.

Comment: второй вариант мне кажется странным, никогда не слышал его. Сам использовал только первый `наебну́лся`. Также мне кажется странным минусование вопроса, вполне разумный

Answer (score 2):

Несмотря на то, что обе формы без приставки `на` существуют: `ёбнулся` и `ебану́лся` (c буквой а), с приставкой "правильной" (общеупотребимой и не режущей слух) является только `наебну́лся`

Comment: Почему вы так считаете? Я тоже встречал первый вариант существенно, на порядки больше чем второй - и об этом написал в своём ответе - , а например, "выёбнулся" не встречал никогда - но у меня нет никаких источников, которые могли бы подтвердить или опровергнуть это утверждение.  На чём строите своё утверждение вы?

Comment: Своё утверждение строю лишь на статистически/эмпирическом опыте носителя языка. Статистически я не слышал, чтобы так кто-либо когда-либо говорил, а эмпирически чувствую, что слово неправильное (режет слух). Полагаю, что в данном случае, когда у нас нет авторитетов вроде Розенталя, этот способ справедливым.

Comment: ну тогда в общем-то вы утверждаете более менее то же, что и я. Вот и все правила, которыми мы располагаем.

Answer (score 1):

Само это разделение на "правильно" и "неправильно" в данном случае попросту лишено смысла. Как правильно "ёбнулся" или "ебанулся" (сейчас придут и объяснят, что первое это "сошёл с ума", а второе - стукнулся - ну или наоборот, но это не так)? Если вам нужен менее эпатажный пример, то как правильно "вы правы" с ударением на первый слог или на последний?

Да так и так правильно, потому что по факту употребляется и та и та форма, если же говорить о частотности то по моему личному опыту "ебану́лся" услышать можно с большей вероятностью. Но субъективный опыт зачастую не отражает объективного положения дел.

Никаких хоть в какой-то степени "регуляторных" грамматических документов нет. Дитмар Эльяшевич Розенталь нам ничего не сказал.

Ну ещё я хотел привести релевантную цитату из Довлатова (ударения проставлены мной для удобства):

> «Прислали к нам сержанта из Москвы. Весьма интеллигентного юношу, сына
>   писателя. Желая показаться завзятым вохровцем, он без конца матерился.
>
> Раз он прикрикнул на какого-то зека:
>
> — Ты что, ебну́лся?!
>
> (Именно так поставив ударение.)
>
> Зек реагировал основательно:
>
> — Гражданин сержант, вы не правы. Можно сказать — ёбнулся, ебанулся и
>   наебну́лся. А ебну́лся — такого слова в русском литературном языке, уж
>   извините, нет…

Comment: не согласен. У ненормативной лексики, как у всякой другой есть свои правильные/неправильные формы, так как это те же слова, возникшие в языке естественным образом. Вами рассматриваемые слова  "ёбнулся" или "ебанулся" допустимы оба, в вопросе же у ОПа допустим только первый. Розенталь об этом, может, и не писал, но это не значит, что тут нет "правильного ответа".

Comment: @user7808407 так факт словоупотребления и есть "правило" - говорят так и так - вот просто факт того что так говорят - это и есть подтверждение того, что так можно.

Comment: нууу... это не корректно: если я внезапно начну говорить `ёбанулся`, это не отменит того факта, что для носителей языка это будет резать слух и казаться неправильным. Ну и не `лишено смысла` спрашивать тут, какая форма слова правильная.

Comment: @user7808407 я и не говорил, что это лишено смысла - я же дал ответ. Если вы считаете, что статистический подход некорректен, и правильность словоупотребления нужно определять по каким-то ещё правилам - то собственно вы можете тоже дать ответ. Но имейте ввиду, что ответ "я никогда второй формы не слышал, следовательно скорее всего первый правильный" - это и есть статистический подход.

Comment: я один здесь не понимаю зачем на вопрос о формах наебну́лся/наёбнулся @shabunc отвечает про _другие_ формы? (ёбнулся/ебану́лся)